# Wrapping http in a service

Tags: angular

As I haven't been able to figure out how to setup defaults for the http service, I figured I'd create an `ApiService` that wrapped the http service, setting up the headers and other options I'd need when getting/setting data to my API. Unfortunately, I'm getting a very confusing error, and I'm not sure if it's an issue with my understanding of observables or Angular.

For example, right now in my `ApiService`, I have the following method:

```
post(path, data): Observable<Response> {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });
    let params = new URLSearchParams(data);
    return this.http
        .post(environment.apiDomain + path, params, options)
}
```

As far as I understand, the `.post` method returns an Observable, thus why I typed the output as such.

Then in my `LoginService`, I have this method:

```
validateCredentials(email, password) {
    return this.api
        .post('/login/validateCredentials', { email: email, password: password })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
}
```

But I get this error:

```
The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
  Type argument candidate 'Response' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'Response'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType'.
```

I don't understand it. I know the error stems from the `.map` as if I comment it out, the error goes away, but that doesn't really help me. I don't know what parameter 'T' is, nor do I get how Response is not valid, especially as it is the same as Response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below compiles for me. I'm importing all the types first as you can see the code with `import` statements.

Next the service class is decorated with `@Injectable` so that Angular can provide an instance of this service to the consumer.

Next, I've just used the same code and added type for email, password and a return type of the method.

I created an object of type any named as api so that I can mimic your base service class. Otherwise, everything should work for you too.

You use that base class post method with a valid url and body, then map the response and return its json data to the caller - component in this case.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    validateCredentials(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.api.post('/login/validateCredentials', { email: email, password: password })
            .map((response: Response) => { return response.json(); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooooh! I didn't include response into the LoginService, as it wasn't using it; I made the stupid assumption that it would know how to cast it automatically. By importing `Response` from http, it works! And I understand it better now.

Comment: great! Yup importing typings is very important and I'm sure that will be your first thing to check from now on. :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that typescript compiler cannot infer the data type of returned response. So you can remove the data type from "response" param in the map function and it should work. Also, you dont need to return anything from within map function because you are already saying that return the result of post call and do the mapping to JSON. Do it like this:

```
validateCredentials(email, password) {
    return this.api
        .post('/login/validateCredentials', { email: email, password: password })
        .map(response => response.json());
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: The other response helped me realize I have to import `Response` to get it to recognize properly. Though your response about properly using the fat arrow function was really useful too, thanks.